# Unresolved reference in Fragment, even when layout is there, won't use deprecated plugin kotlin-extensions

Tags: android, kotlin

So, findViewbyId does not work in this case, binding does not seem to work as well, at least I haven't found a working solution to it, and I'm stuck. I've read countless answers here
but none of them seem to do the trick since it looks like it's different for fragments.

Please do not answer with kotlin-android-extension, that is deprecated and I'd like to not use it
since most of my code is already under binding.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        frameLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_augmented_face, container, false) as FrameLayout
        surfaceView = frameLayout?.findViewById<View>(R.id.surface_view) as GLSurfaceView
        surfaceView?.let {
            it.preserveEGLContextOnPause = true
            it.setEGLContextClientVersion(2)
            it.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0) // Alpha used for plane blending.
            it.setRenderer(this)
            it.renderMode = GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY
            it.setWillNotDraw(false)
        }

        return frameLayout
    }
```

These two lines here, they are unresolved references:

```
frameLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_augmented_face, container, false) as FrameLayout
surfaceView = frameLayout?.findViewById<View>(R.id.surface_view) as GLSurfaceView
```

I'm not sure if it is because it's a Fragment and not AppCompatActivity that I can't make it work?
What are my options here?

Edit here to clarify what I've tried:

I use instead id 'kotlin-parcelize', and viewBinding true

Also tried the Fragment binding instructions on the documentation, so it would look like this.:

```
lateinit var _binding: AugmentedFaceFragment
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

...

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        _binding = AugmentedFaceListener.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

And now I get unresolved reference on inflate. (Even before adding the rest of the code).

Seems apart from writing the right way here, I was also setting the wrong name of the binding, instead of the xml file I was writing the class name. Here is the working code:

```
private var _binding: FragmentAugmentedFaceBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentAugmentedFaceBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        frameLayout = binding.root
        surfaceView = binding.surfaceView as GLSurfaceView
        surfaceView?.let {
            it.preserveEGLContextOnPause = true
            it.setEGLContextClientVersion(2)
            it.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0) // Alpha used for plane blending.

            it.setRenderer(this)
            it.renderMode = GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY
            it.setWillNotDraw(false)
        }
        return frameLayout
    }

//Also need to remember to nullify the binding onDestroy:

override fun onDestroy() {
        _binding = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get rid of the `kotlin-android-extension` declaration?  I think that would be the problem on why it cannot find these method declration.

Either way, you should really use viewBinding/dataBinding instead of this old-school way of grabbing onto your UI components.  Is a lot easier to use and much more convenient.

Here are some links

View binding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Data binding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Choose your weapons wisely!

**UPDATE:**
While using `viewBinding`, all of your XML classes should be automatically generating a `*binding* class that you can then use to access your UI components.

For the example above with a fragment called `AugmentedFaceFragment`, you should be able to access your binding class and inflate it by calling:

```
_binding = AugmentedFaceFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer, I've updated the question with more info.

Comment: If you're already using `viewBinding`, then all of your XML classes should have an automatically-generated binding class, as per this part of the doc I sent: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#usage.  What is the name of your class?  You should try: `ClassNameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)` as shown here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had some personal problems to deal with IRL. Thank you for your answers, even tough I was reading that doc as I pointed on my original question, I wasn't getting the result expected. What happened was that instead of the xml name I was writing the class name, maybe was too tired that day. Will update the question with the working code.